# how can I get the total bytes sent and received using python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, urllib2

Is there a way to calculate the total sent and total received bytes in python 2.7 application using urllib2 library? I cannot see any method or variable holding this value when I look at the methods/variables of Request object and response which can be seen below. I checked the urllib2 library however I could not find what I wanted.

Here is my simple example;

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# encoding: utf-8
from __future__ import print_function
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request('http://example.com')
print(dir(req))
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print(dir(response))
the_page = response.read()
print("Length:" + str(len(the_page)))
```

Output is:

```
['_Request__fragment', '_Request__original', '__doc__', '__getattr__', '__init__', '__module__', '_tunnel_host', 'add_data', 'add_header', 'add_unredirected_header', 'data', 'get_data', 'get_full_url', 'get_header', 'get_host', 'get_method', 'get_origin_req_host', 'get_selector', 'get_type', 'has_data', 'has_header', 'has_proxy', 'header_items', 'headers', 'host', 'is_unverifiable', 'origin_req_host', 'port', 'set_proxy', 'type', 'unredirected_hdrs', 'unverifiable']
['__doc__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__module__', '__repr__', 'close', 'code', 'fileno', 'fp', 'getcode', 'geturl', 'headers', 'info', 'msg', 'next', 'read', 'readline', 'readlines', 'url']
Length:1270
```

Web server may send the content compressed, of course simple `len(the_page)` is not enough for total received bytes. My constraint is not to use any other library other than urllib2, urllib, httplib under python2.7 to achieve this.

Any help will be appreciated to find the total sent bytes and total received bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The webserver does not automatically compress the response. The compression method (gzip, deflate) depends on your request.

If you want to receive a compressed payload, you have to request it:

```
req.add_header('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
```

... and you have to unzip the response by yourself.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
# encoding: utf-8
from __future__ import print_function
import urllib2
import gzip
import zlib
import StringIO

req = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.com')
req.add_header('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

the_page = response.read()
print("Length before decompression:" + str(len(the_page)))
if response.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip':
    the_page = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO.StringIO(the_page)).read()
elif response.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'deflate':
    the_page = zlib.decompress(the_page)

print("Length after decompression:" + str(len(the_page)))
```

But anyway ... with "len(response.read())" you only measure the length of the http payload without any headers.

For measuring the sending bytes i've found a hacky solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
# encoding: utf-8
from __future__ import print_function
import urllib2
import gzip
import zlib
import StringIO
import httplib
import socket

class CountingHTTPConnection(httplib.HTTPConnection):
    bytes_sent = 0

    def __init__(self, host, port=None, strict=None,
                 timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, source_address=None):
        self._send = self.send
        self.send = self.counting_send
        httplib.HTTPConnection.__init__(self, host, port=None, strict=None,
                                        timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, source_address=None)

    def counting_send(self, data):
            CountingHTTPConnection.bytes_sent += len(data)
            self._send(data) 

class CountingHTTPHandler(urllib2.HTTPHandler):
    def http_open(self, req):
        return self.do_open(CountingHTTPConnection, req) 

req = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.com')
opener = urllib2.build_opener(CountingHTTPHandler())
req.add_header('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate')


response = opener.open(req)
the_page = response.read()
print("Length before decompression:" + str(len(the_page)))
if response.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip':
    the_page = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO.StringIO(the_page)).read()
elif response.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'deflate':
    the_page = zlib.decompress(the_page)

print("Length after decompression:" + str(len(the_page)))
print("bytes sent: {}".format(CountingHTTPConnection.bytes_sent))
```

... note that the code above only works for http connections.

Comment: Thanks, what about the sent bytes?

Comment: how you calculate the bytes received is very deductive and detailed, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
result = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com')
print result.headers['content-length']
```

which actually equals to

```
result = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com')
print len(result.read())
```

that means the number of bytes you received is nothing more than the number of characters in the page that you request.

Comment: AFAIK, if you fetch chunked data, content length may not be correct.